# Regex for extracting path in URL after schema and authority

Tags: java, regex, url

I am trying to write a regular expression to extract everything after schema and authority in a URL. For example if I have

```
http://myHost:8080/Starter/docs/start.jsp
```

I need the regex in Java which gets "Starter/docs/start.jsp".

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: The actual official standard for URLs includes an example regex for parsing: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-B - there are possibly edge-cases it doesn't cover, but should be good.

Comment: Thanks cloudfeet. I think I got it, following works for my case  ^[^#]*?://.*?(/.*)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual official standard for URLs, [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) includes an example regex for parsing:

> #### Appendix B.  Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression
>
> As the "first-match-wins" algorithm is identical to the "greedy"
> disambiguation method used by POSIX regular expressions, it is
> natural and commonplace to use a regular expression for parsing the
> potential five components of a URI reference.
>
> The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a
> well-formed URI reference into its components.
>
> ```
>  ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
>   12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
> ```

> The numbers in the second line above are only to assist readability;
> they indicate the reference points for each subexpression (i.e., each
> paired parenthesis).  We refer to the value matched for subexpression
>  as $.  For example, matching the above expression to

> ```
>  http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
> ```

> results in the following subexpression matches:

> ```
>  $1 = http:
>  $2 = http
>  $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
>  $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
>  $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
>  $6 = <undefined>
>  $7 = <undefined>
>  $8 = #Related
>  $9 = Related
> ```

> where  indicates that the component is not present, as is
> the case for the query component in the above example.  Therefore, we
> can determine the value of the five components as

> ```
>  scheme    = $2
>  authority = $4
>  path      = $5
>  query     = $7
>  fragment  = $9
> ```

If you're looking for a fuzzier match that can handle misformed URLs, there are many open-source URI parsers (at least for JavaScript, e.g. [`parseuri`](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri)) which you could inspect to see how their regexes work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're always using the same domain, you don't need regular expressions.

```
str = str.replace("http://myHost:8080", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
String url = "https://myHost:8080/Starter/docs/start.jsp";
String pattern = "^[^#]*?://.*?/(.*)$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(url);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use substring for this problem.